# How to execute more than one query in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to execute two queries, one for insertion and another one for updating. If insertion is successful then I have to update an entry. Is is possible to use  PreparedStatement?
I also want to set parameters dynamically.

Comment: Yes it's possible to do, but you need to ask a more direct question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [setAutoCommit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29) to false, execute two separate statements and then commit the transaction manually.

Comment: Thankyou for reply What i want,i got here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: This looks fine. Let me know if you get stuck anywhere! Good luck.

Comment: Ya i will post, keep in touch